# JVM does not load jar file from Enviroment Variable classpath using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

consider the following code.

```
    JavaVM * jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options;
    options.optionString ="-Djava.class.path=D:\\Work\\mybytes.jar";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; 
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
    JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if(ret >=0)
    {
      jclass myBytesClass=env->FindClass("MyBytes");
      jmethodID myByteConstructor=env->GetMethodID(myBytesClass,"<init>","()V");
      myByteObj=env->NewObject(myBytesClass,myByteConstructor,NULL);
      char* printBytes=env->GetMethodID(myBytesClass,"printBytes","([B)V");
    }
```

I do not want this statement in Code.

**options.optionString ="-Djava.class.path=D:\Work\mybytes.jar";**

I want to add this jar file in classpath in environment variable.
but when i add this jar file to classpath variable the jvm does not load this jar file.
i do not know why this happen?

Comment: Can you format your code properly -- indent each line 4 spaces.

Comment: Long time ago, but did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
```

Move your setting of the option string after that line.
(Think you can actually remove it all together, don't think its needed anymore)