# JNI FindClass fails with imports

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call my java class from c++ (ms vc 2008) with JNI, but the problem is that FindClass works only when there are not imported packages in my java class. If I add any package (for example java.lang.String or java.io.File) the FindClass fails and returns no value. Why?

C++ CODE: /////////////////////////////////////

```
JNIEnv *env;
JavaVM * jvm;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
JavaVMOption options;
options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\\mypackage.jar";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = &options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
if(env == NULL)
    printf("\nJVM Failed\n");       

jclass cls = env->FindClass("mypackage/test/MyClass");

if(cls==0)
{
printf("\nFindClass Failed\n");
}
```

JAVA CODE: /////////////////////////////////////

```
package mypackage.test;

import java.io.File;   //if I comment this row, FindClass works...

public class MyClass {

}
```

UPDATE:

THIS IS MY CODE: http://www.sendspace.com/file/233tfm

- copy in C:\JNITest
- change the working directory in the properties\debug settings of the project
- check the optionString in JNI_test1.cpp

many thanks,
Riccardo

Comment: it just doesn't find anything or throws some exceptions? what happens if you try FindClass("java.io.File")?

Comment: jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/io/File"); works, but i need to import java.io.File in my java class

Comment: can you post your code as it is now

Comment: this is my code: http://www.sendspace.com/file/233tfm

- copy in C:\JNITest
- change the working directory in the properties\debug settings of the project
- check the optionString in JNI_test1.cpp

thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. If I select in Eclipse\Jar Export\ the option "Export generated class files and resources" AND I put some import in my java class, the generated JAR file will not include any .class file. Instead the option "Export all output folders for checked projects" works anytime. I don't know why, but I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be because your class path is only c:\mypackage.jar when you create the JVM. I think the system class path has to be specified. Class path can be set as options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\mypackage.jar;C:\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\lib\rt.jar";  Please change based on where rt.jar is on your system....

Comment: I have found the problem. If I select in Eclipse\Jar Export\ the option "Export generated class files and resources" AND I put some import in my java class the generated JAR file will not include any .class file. I don't know why, but I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

The VM cannot find rt.jar and all the other classes. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257848/jvm-does-not-load-jar-file-from-enviroment-variable-classpath-using-jni) suggests to run `JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);` before you set other options.

Comment: @Riccardo: i tried running this code on my linux machine and it seems to work fine with the only change that in `JNI_CreateJavaVM` you should pass `&jvm` instead of `jvm`.

Comment: thank you... so probably the problem is related to the system (classpath, path, or similar)...